# How to access a key named with asterisk?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

There is a method in Wikimedia API that gives a localized title.

**Examples:**

Cloud: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=Cloud&prop=langlinks&lllimit=500&lllang=ru&continue=

Rain: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=Rain&prop=langlinks&lllimit=500&lllang=ru&continue=

Cloud response:

```
{
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{
      "pages":{
         "47515":{
            "pageid":47515,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Cloud",
            "langlinks":[
               {
                  "lang":"ru",
                  "*":"\u041e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u043a\u0430"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Rain response:

```
{
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{
      "pages":{
         "19009110":{
            "pageid":19009110,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Rain",
            "langlinks":[
               {
                  "lang":"ru",
                  "*":"Дождь"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Important note:** integer container under pages (e.g. 19009110) is always different, because it equals page id.

C# code:

```
dynamic datacontainer_RUname2 = JObject.Parse(cleanJson_string_RUname);
String localizedName = datacontainer_RUname.[HERE SHOULD BE *];
```

How can I access a key named with asterisk '*'?

Comment: Shouldn't this depend entirely on whatever the code does that deserializes the JSON into C# objects? Are you using any library? Can you add an appropriate tag and/or remark in your question?

Comment: just as a side note: your provided json is not valid...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair it is a part of response, please go the link above and check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    string content;
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        const string url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=Cloud&prop=langlinks&lllimit=500&lllang=ru&continue=";
        content = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    }

    var obj = JObject.Parse(content);
    var query = obj["query"];
    var pages = query["pages"].Value<JObject>();
    var page = pages.PropertyValues().First();
    var langLinks = page["langlinks"].Values<JObject>();
    var firstLangLink = langLinks.First();
    var localizedName = firstLangLink["*"];
```

See a [working demo with live data](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gnlfWA).

Comment: Very nice! Thanks. But.... I can't get "var page" for each request because it is dynamicly changing, it is equal to page id

Comment: @IvanFazaniuk you should add this to your question :) I will adapt my code.

Comment: sorry :) didn't expect so much help with deep explaining :)

Comment: Wonderful! Very simple and works perfectly. Worked on a bunch of such requests last 2 days and after this answer I should go to SO administration and ask them to delete 80% of answers with tag list C#, JSON, deserialize

Answer (score 1):

Just use the normal indexing on the object.

```
string localizedName = obj["*"];
```

In your case... to get to your object, you can do this query in both cases.  To collect all links returned from the query:

```
var allLinks =
    from page in response.SelectToken("query.pages").Values()
    from link in page["langlinks"]
    select (string)link["*"];
```

Comment: How do you figure? All `JTokens` can be accessed using indexers. Assuming the object reference points to the object that contains the property, it just needs to be indexed.  The question asks, `How to access a key named with asterisk?`... this is the answer. As far as I'm concerned, it's not my job to figure out how to get to that token that he wants to access, all that we can assume is that he has it.

Comment: I do certainly understand your point of view, but there's an example given which clearly shows that the OP does not  have the correct token. So a certain amount of help is obligatory. Transforming `datacontainer_RUname.[HERE SHOULD BE *]` into `datacontainer_RUname2["*"]` is a bit too obvious, isn't it?

Comment: Well considering it took many edits just to include the relevant and correct information, who knows _what_ was intended.  When I answered, there was a lot missing and just downright wrong, so I answered what could be answered given the circumstances.

Comment: ey, a downvote isn't final, is it? thanks for the edit!